# Change Editor.java class in Android Studio, Save, Run, Debug -> Possible?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

In Android Studio I can change the Android API code and save it. I assume this change is not pushed to the emulator?

Do I need to download the whole AOSP and compile a new android.jar or is there an easier way to change for example Editor.java and try out things in Android Studio?

Comment: No. For apply changes you should rebuild emulator images from source.

Comment: @HotIceCream Is there a simpler way, see my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to change an Android api... you wouldn't be able to install the app on anyone's phone.

But yah, Android is open source and you can download AOSP, change an api, and compile a device image.That'd be the only way to do it.

What is your end goal here? There probably is an easier way to accomplish it.

Comment: I don't want to push things to Play or other devices. I just want to debug an error I have in my own code. Doing that I like to comment out or/and possible change small portions of the standard API, to be able to understand what is going on...

Comment: Why don't you post a question with your code and the error you are getting. It'll be much faster to debug your code than to download and compile aosp. I promise.

Comment: I don't have an error code but trying to understand the framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476806/compound-drawable-and-seterror-problematic